# Not able to re-index Magento Catalog search Index using shell command

Tags: php, shell, magento

I have a magento installation which has 25,000+ products. When Im trying to re-index using the following shell command

```
php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

the following error is appearing when i run the mentioned command in putty

```
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Im not able to load my site since the index is all wrong. How can i re-index catalog search?

Answer (score 1):

That's a mysql error not in magento. Probably you have a big tables.  You need to change the value for `max_allowed_packet` in your mysql configuration. You can change the value in **my.ini** file in your server `max_allowed_packet=16M` then reatart your mysql server (if linux srever)

```
service mysqld start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

, or by **shell command** (for this you need to logged in to your mysql server)

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

to see the value,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

for more information [read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html)

Comment: max_allowed_packet is 32M when the question was posted. I was not able to re index with that

Comment: Did you restart your mysql server ..? Changes applicable only if it is restarted.